# Xceed DateTimePicker, isEnabled time picker

Tags: c#, wpf, xceed

I using xceed components in our project.
Now what I need to do is `readOnly` property for `timePicker`.
Currently I got this:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Width="Auto" MinWidth="140" Height="25" Margin="2">
     <TextBlock Text="Od " TextAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15"/>
     <xceed:DateTimePicker Format="Custom" 
                           FormatString="{Binding Path=CustomDateTimeFormat, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"  
                           FontSize="15" Value="{Binding Path=FromDate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">

     </xceed:DateTimePicker>
 </DockPanel>
```

But I want `timePicker` from this `DateTimePicker` `readOnly = true` or `false`, depend on conditions.
Im using MVVM pattern.

Comment: If you are fine with collapsing the `Visibility`, you can try using [TimePickerVisibility](https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit~Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.DateTimePicker~TimePickerVisibility.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a `DataTrigger` that changes the `IsReadOnly` property based on some property in the VM:

```
<xctk:DateTimePicker 
            FontSize="15" Value="{Binding Path=FromDate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <xctk:DateTimePicker.Style>
                <Style TargetType="xctk:DateTimePicker">
                    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeProperty}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="SomeValue"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </xctk:DateTimePicker.Style>

        </xctk:DateTimePicker>
```

Comment: Yes. I actually solved it with this, but instead of DateTimePicker i used only TimePicker. :) User can move date back and forward. :)